# Searching on Date Fields when some date rows are NULL on the back-end

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime

User Picks some `from` and `to` dates and with `SqlBuilder` I am creating the query string to be run the database records. So part of it that generated query may look like this:

```
WHERE  ( t1.From_Date >= @from_date AND t1.To_Date <= @to_date )
```

BUT for some reason that I am not aware of, if I go to SQL Server and see the rows some of them have `NULL` in their `from` or `to` columns. So it causes my query to not return those rows. 
Is there a way I can fix this in C# side of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you WANT to include those rows just adjust your WHERE caluse:

```
WHERE  t1.From_Date IS NULL OR
       t1.To_Date   IS NULL OR
       ( t1.From_Date >= @from_date AND t1.To_Date <= @to_date )
```

Comment: from and to are currently getting built by a  command like "sqlBuilder.AddParameter" So not sure how I fit that solution into what I have?  Thanks for help

Comment: They are getting added like this: sqlBuilder.AddParameter("@from_date, myObject.From_date) So like I said I don't know how to fit your solution with my code

Comment: Well I don't know what you have other than the `WHERE` clause;  If you are building the `WHERE` clause in C# than add that code to your question.

Comment: Are you using Dapper's SqlBuilder?

Comment: It is EntitySQLBuilder.. Now I even searhed for the word "WHERE" in this part of code and there is none! I dunno how it is getting generated

Answer (score 0):

I would fix the query to do something like this:

```
where (isnull(t1.From_Date, @from_date) >= @from_date 
    and isnull(t1.To_Date, @to_date) <= @to_date)
```

Variation:

```
where (t1.From_Date is null or t1.From_Date >= @from_date) 
    and (t1.To_Date is null or t1.To_Date <= @to_date)
```

Comment: from and to are currently getting built by a  command like "sqlBuilder.AddParameter" So not sure how I fit that solution into what I have?  Thanks for help

Comment: They are getting added like this: sqlBuilder.AddParameter("@from_date, myObject.From_date)  So like I said I don't know how to fit your solution with my code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you fix your data first, otherwise just do a 'select *' and as you rifle through the records, instantiate a class that loads each property, if prop is null make it whatever value..save class object to hashtable and use set of records as you like.. KEEP IN Mind, this is only if you have a need to filter or present the data in a certain way..Use queries below if you just want to omit the records..